# JavaFX 8 TreeView displays incorrect String when cell is clicked to edit

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, textfield, treecell

I'm using the following code from Oracle:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class TreeViewSample extends Application {

List<Employee> employees = Arrays.<Employee>asList(
        new Employee("Ethan Williams", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Emma Jones", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Michael Brown", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Anna Black", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Rodger York", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Susan Collins", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Mike Graham", "IT Support"),
        new Employee("Judy Mayer", "IT Support"),
        new Employee("Gregory Smith", "IT Support"),
        new Employee("Jacob Smith", "Accounts Department"),
        new Employee("Isabella Johnson", "Accounts Department"));
TreeItem<String> rootNode = 
    new TreeItem<String>("MyCompany Human Resources");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    rootNode.setExpanded(true);
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        TreeItem<String> empLeaf = new TreeItem<String>(employee.getName());
        boolean found = false;
        for (TreeItem<String> depNode : rootNode.getChildren()) {
            if (depNode.getValue().contentEquals(employee.getDepartment())){
                depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            TreeItem depNode = new TreeItem(employee.getDepartment());
            rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
            depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
        }
    }

    stage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");
    VBox box = new VBox();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 400, 300);
    scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(rootNode);
    treeView.setEditable(true);
    treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
        @Override
        public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
            return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl();
        }
    });

    box.getChildren().add(treeView);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private final class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<String> {

    private TextField textField;
    private ContextMenu addMenu = new ContextMenu();

    public TextFieldTreeCellImpl() {
        MenuItem addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Add Employee");
        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
        addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            public void handle(Event t) {
                TreeItem newEmployee = 
                    new TreeItem<String>("New Employee");
                        getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newEmployee);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                if (
                    !getTreeItem().isLeaf()&&getTreeItem().getParent()!= null
                ){
                    setContextMenu(addMenu);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });  

    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}

public static class Employee {

    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleStringProperty department;

    private Employee(String name, String department) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.department = new SimpleStringProperty(department);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String fName) {
        name.set(fName);
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department.get();
    }

    public void setDepartment(String fName) {
        department.set(fName);
    }
}
}
```

This code produces a GUI with a very basic, editable TreeView.  However, when clicking around the cells that populate the tree, eventually, the text fields used for editing will begin to display incorrect information (information that is contained within the tree, but that is not represented by the cell being edited).  I do not understand why this is happening, and I haven't found any reference of this happening anywhere on Google or elsewhere on StackOverflow.  If anyone could help me understand why this is occuring, I'd be very happy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your application and I have found only one weird thing. When you create the edit textfield once, the unsaved information will be visible in that textfield later.

This modification will solve it:

```
@ Override
public void cancelEdit() {
    super.cancelEdit();

    this.setText(this.getItem());
    this.textField.setText(this.getItem());
    this.setGraphic(this.getTreeItem().getGraphic());
}
```

Comment: Maybe better is just to do `textField.setText(getItem());` after the existing `if(textField == null) { ... }`.

Comment: Yep, that works, I just got distracted by the this.setText(null); (and I put it in the cancelEdit method)